# Div forming a line inside another div

Tags: css, html, position, line

How do I create a div with width size: 1024px, height: 200px and another div inside starting position with size 990px ​​width: 20px, height: 200px forming a line.

I started to do but I'm not progressing:

Here is the code:

**CSS:**

```
div.wrap, div.header
{
    width:1024px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
div.header, header1
{
    height:100px;
    background-color:Purple;
}
div.header header1
{
    background-color:Gray;
    left:990px;
    position:fixed;
}
```

**Html:**

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="header">
    <div class="header1"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

As should be the result:
[image: Should be result]

Comment: Do the two columns have to be equal height? *(should the background colours extend all the way down?)*

Comment: Yes.. shall be equal to the height, this is just the header.
The background color is white.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** Please note that you have a typo in your css, it should be `.header1` instead of `header1`.

To answer your question:

```
div.wrap, div.header
{
    width:1024px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position: relative;    // added
}
div.header, .header1    // typo fixed, header1 is not a valid element
{
    height:100px;
    background-color:Purple;
}
div.header header1
{
    background-color:Gray;
    left:990px;
    position:absolute;    // changed
    width: 20px;    // added
}
```

However, can´t you just use the `border` property?

Comment: I can yes, but the result should be the same
how would the CSS?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/5ZuUZ/